# Shouldn't [laravel-eloquent] be merged or 'synonymed' into [eloquent]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I was looking through some Laravel related questions today and I came across the [laravel-eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel-eloquent/info) tag, which has 261 questions right now. The [eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/eloquent/info) tag has 9100 questions and is, in my opinion, the leading tag and should be the only tag.

I don't know why the laravel-eloquent one was created, but it doesn't seem like it should have it's own tag.

I would like to propose to either merge them all to eloquent, or create a synonym, for whenever people start to type Laravel while looking for eloquent.